Не обязательные индексные сигнатуры
Пытаюсь определить тип функции с не обязательными свойствами того же типа, что и возвращаемое значение
type MyFunction<T> = {
    (): T;
    [key: string | symbol]: T;
};

При попытке его использовать
let test: MyFunction<number> = () => 15;

TS выдает ошибку

Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'MyFunction'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '() => number'.

Как обозначить, что эти свойства не обязательные?

только что-то такое приходит в голову

а зачем нужно это странное, какую задачу решаете?

@nörbörnën Пытаюсь понять границы дозволенного) Запись же вроде верная с точки зрения TS, с объектом такой ошибки нет. "as any" - это понятно, но не то.

Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, вы что-то подобное хотели?

@MoloF Нет, я хочу иметь возможность добавлять функции свойства с результатом ее выполнения под заранее не известными ключами.

@hlearn вы может добавить в вопрос то что вы хотите получить и в каком виде? Какой у вас реальный кейс? Я до сих пор на словах не могу понять что должно получиться в результате

@MoloF В результате должна получиться функция, которой можно добавлять свойства под любыми ключами, в этом весь кейс и заключается. Для чего это нужно, вопрос десятый. Как его решить другим способом - не вопрос, уже сделано. Но способ, указанный в текущем вопросе, предпочтительней. Мне не понятно, почему TS считает индексные свойства функции обязательными, если то же объявление для объекта делает их опциональными?
